# check for password when using password_digest rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-5

So I implemented an auth system on my rails API using the `knock` and `bcript` gems. I hence added `has_secure_password` in my user model and when a new user is created, it has a `password_digest` attribute in the db.

I am now building the possibility for the end user to change his/her password. For security reasons, I want to ask for the old password, check wether the old password given is the right one, and if so, update the user's password. Otherwise, send an error message.

So here is what I wrote:

```
def update_password
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
     if params[:password][:oldPassword] === @user.password
       if @user.update(password: params[:password][:newPassword])
         render json: @user
       else
         render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
       end
     else
       render json: {erreur: "the current password is wrong"}, status: :unprocessable_entity
     end
   end
```

My problem here is: `params[:password][:oldPassword] === @user.password` to check for current password validity doesn't work: it will always return `false`.

How can I do this the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a method [`user.authenticate(pass)`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password).

Comment: why their is an error if password is wrong. instead of running the else if password not match.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the password type against a digested hash, thats causing it to always return false.
i.e the user types his old password "123456", but the system cant access that string, when it queries the database it return something like "$2a$12$.FMAPyhKwOyg.bHti8aFzuOcBw1w2ho1HI5IOloa4vlSMnAMMNtJC". Thats a security measure caused by bcript.
To check the it you must use the .authenticate(:password) method, it will encrypt "123456" into a hash and then match it against the database.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not what you are looking for but I ran into a similar issue a few months ago, a solution to compare properly those passwords is to use `bcrypt` as below:

```rb
BCrypt::Password.new(new_password) == (user.password)
```

The order of the elements in the expression is important because Rails set the correct comparer, meaning that the `bcrypt` instance needs to be on the left.